# Is my question about motivating my mother in law to take her medicine off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question and it was immediately voted to close:

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26409/how-do-i-motivate-my-mother-in-law-to-take-her-medicine-on-her-own

I looked in the help center and it probably would fall somewhere between discipline and behavior?

> We welcome questions on topics like these:
>   matters of upbringing,
>   ...
>   language development,
>   behavior and social skills,
>   discipline and punishment,

Additionally, the strategies I am lookig for are ones very often employed by parents. I'm sure "[how do I motivate my teenage daughter to](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?q=How%20do%20i%20motivate%20my%20daughter%20to) take her medicine on her own" would certainly be on topic.

There have been other questions which have been about parents, like this one:

[Mother won't let me buy a new car (cultural clash in parent-child relationships)](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26281/mother-wont-let-me-buy-a-new-car-cultural-clash-in-parent-child-relationships)

Is my question off topic?

Comment: Parents have more methods of coercion (if you will) with teens living under their roof than with mothers-in-law who live independently. The original question will not be answered by the answers to the edited one. As a physician, I suggest you take it up with her physicians. They have resources to help with problems exactly like this. Most of all, mild dementia must be ruled out, after which your mother in law needs to be convinced of the need to take her meds by a good diabetologist. If she's not mildly demented and understands the consequences, there's nothing anyone can do about her choices.

Comment: I've been around stackexchange long enough to understand why my question got closed, but it still sucks to see someone you care about neglect their health and be completely helpless to stop them. Thanks for your input.

Comment: There is a Health.SE site now. Have you tried posting there?

Comment: No, I didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree this is off topic. As our scope says:

> Parenting Stack Exchange is for parents, grandparents, nannies and others who care for children.